# Select age from MySql and display it in Chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, .net

I am using this command to get the ages for all the users in my database:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d/%m/%Y'))), '%Y')+0 AS age 
FROM users ;
```

And i want to get the count for each age and diplay it in the Chart control in `asp.net`.

Somethig like :

```
Age count
15  30
16  19
18  46
```

How should be the select command for this?

Comment: did count(*) dont help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT age , count(age) FROM (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d/%m/%Y'))), '%Y')+0 AS age FROM users ) t GROUP BY age
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like :

```
SELECT AGE , COUNT(*) as count
(
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW())- TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%d/%m/%Y'))), '%Y')+0 AS age 
FROM users
) AS A 
GROUP BY AGE
```

This will create a group of same age user and count it .